# TYPO3 Flexform: only show original records in select and hide translations

Tags: typo3

Maybe this is a simple question. I have this flexform configuration to select tt_news items:

```
<selectNews>
    <TCEforms>
        <label>LLL:fileadmin/setup/locallang_xml/locallang_db.xml:tx_zoatac_pi2.selectNews</label>
        <config>
            <type>group</type>
            <internal_type>db</internal_type>
            <allowed>tt_news</allowed>
            <minitems>0</minitems>
            <maxitems>100</maxitems>
            <size>10</size>
        </config>
    </TCEforms>
</selectNews>
```

Now I want that the select I can only select original items an that translations are hidden.So when I have the same news item in English, Frech and German I only want to see the English one.

Comment: Similar question, but for "select" ty:pe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140814/typo3-how-to-show-the-right-language-only-in-flexform

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to have any additional WHERE statements in *group* type of field neither in TCA or FlexForm. I've asked similar question a year ago in [TYPO3 mailing lists](http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-english/2012-June/081148.html), but got no responce.

But if you're on TYPO3 6.0 or higher, you may consider to try **filter** property of *group* field-type. Read more about it [here](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Group/Index.html).

Comment: Thnx for the info, but unfortunatly this specific installation ist still T3 4.5

Comment: The link is broken, see https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Group/Index.html